# merge paths with python, from /a/b/c + c/d to /a/b/c/d

Tags: python, os.path

in python, with `os.path.join`, I can join directories paths

```
import os
os.path.join('/usr','opt', 'bin')
'/usr/opt/bin'
```

how I can merge two path ?

from

```
/a/b/c + c/d
```

get

```
/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: What if you have a directory with the same name as the parent? Like what if inside "c" there exists another, totally different, directory named "c"? Some open source projects structure their code like this. Many Python projects have it too because people don't know the right way to build with setuptools and so they place a whole copy of the code inside the top directory. Most of this answer will depend on what you want for these kinds of corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the paths are of the form you give an example for,

```
os.path.join(os.path.split(p1)[0], p2)
```

would do it.